# Chrome-based browsers show wrongly some letters with diacritics on parts of some websites (Wikipedia, Wiktionary)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

This doesn't happen in Firefox or other non-Chrome-based browsers, but it happens in Opera, Thorium or Vivaldi.

The name "Țepeș", for example, looks like this:

[image]

when it should look like this:

[image]

Only *ș* and *ț* letters (with under-letter diacritics) seem affected (they seem to be of a different font set), while *ăîâ* (with above-letter diacritics) are not.

And this only happens in *that* part of the page, the title, not the body of the article.

What could the cause be?

This looks like "a problem with fonts" - but at what level? Can it be fixed?

---

By the way, I see this in Linux and for the moment cannot test on other desktop systems. (The problem is absent on Android, for example.)

Comment: It looks like a font substitution error. The Serif font chrome is using doesn't have diacritics so it is falling back to a Sans Serif font instead. No idea how to fix though (sorry) as I don't use Chrome.

Comment: I am not seeing this issue with Debian 12/Chromium 120. Which fonts do the browsers think they're using? (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20830300)

Comment: @Mokubai - I am more interested in learning about he cause of this than fixing it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @Nnnes - Indeed, testing with a different system (Solus Linux) I don't see this anymore. It seems Ubuntu specific! I will flag to migrate this, or if not I'll move it.

Comment: @cipricus that *is* the cause. The font your program is trying to use lacks certain characters with diacritics and is incorrectly falling back to a different font type (serif vs Sans serif) rather than using a vaguely similar font. That is the cause of what you are seeing. Unless you meant you are *less* interested in the cause than the fix...

Comment: @Mokubai - What I meant is that you don't have to say "sorry" for not providing the fix because I am more interested in the cause than in the fix.  And in the end this is such a marginal problem that I discourage you from bothering with it :)) Now that this is under askubuntu maybe a specific fix will pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

I tested in Word, and the display of these diacritics is
entirely dependent on the font that is used.

If you wish to replace fonts whose diacritics are badly
displayed with other fonts, on some or on all websites,
this requires an extension.

Here are some useful extensions :

- [Font Changer](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/font-changer/obgkjikcnonokgaiablbenkgjcdbknna)

  > You can use this extension to change fonts on all websites, or you can pick and choose certain fonts for certain sites. This gives you the ability to make the web a more consistent or varied place, depending on your taste. When you click the extension’s icon you can choose to modify global fonts, which is how you will change all websites, or you can choose custom settings to set the font for a certain website.
- [Fonts Changer](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/fonts-changer/phkenomnahhgjnmpignadbeandfanbil)

Comment: But how come Firefox doesn't "see" the problem?

Comment: Now I have tested with a different Linux and it's fixed there. I will flag to migrate to askubuntu.